# Media Query, Centering the Viewport, and Skewed margins

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, viewport

I'm trying to make my #titlesec and #forms IDs take up 100 percent of the viewport when they're at 500px or less. The problem is, not only is it not doing that,but it's actually skewed. if you can check them through the chrome developer tools you'll se the margin goes all the way to the right side of the viewport.

Here's my HTML...

```
  <h1 id="title">
      Customer Survey Form
    </h1> 
    <p id="description">Tell us what you think about our product</p>
    </div>

    <div id="forms">
    <form id="survey-form-1">
      <p id="name">Name: <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name"></p>
      <p id="number">Number: <input type="number"  placeholder="10 digits here""></p>
      <p id="email">Email: <input type="text" placeholder="put your email here"></p>
      <p id="email"  >Password: <input type="password" placeholder="password"></p>

    </form>
        <br>
        <p>
             <label>How would you describe yourself?</label>
          <br>
             <select id= "myList">
               <option value = "student">Student</option>
               <option value = "child">Child</option>
               <option value = "parent">Parent</option>

             </select>
          </p>
          <br>
        <form id="survey-form-2">
        <p> Q: How satisfied are you with our product?</p>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="satisfaction" value="Very Satisfied" checked> Very Satisfied </input>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="satisfaction" value="Satisfied" > Satisfied </input>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="satisfaction" value="Kinda Satisfied"> Kinda Satisfied </input>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="satisfaction" value="Not Satisfied"> Not Satisfied </input>
        <br>
        <br>

        <p> Q: What do you like about our product?</p>
         <input type="checkbox" name="likes" value="likes" checked> The product is reliable </input>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="likes" value="Satisfied" > The the kids love it </input>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="likes" value="Kinda Satisfied"> The product is fun </input>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="likes" value="Not Satisfied">The product is long lasting </input>

        </form>
        </div>
```

and here's my CSS...

```
body {
background-color:#3385FF;  
}

#title-sec {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  width:50%;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  left: 25%;
  margin-top:-7px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

}


h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

#forms {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  left: 25%;
}
#survey-form-1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#survey-form-2 {
  text-align:center;
}

input {
  text-align: center;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

  #title-sec {

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
   align-items: stretch;
  background-color: white;
  width:-75%;
  height: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-right: 131.25;

width:75%;    
}

  #forms {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  align-items: center; 
  width: 100%;  

  }
}
```

If you need more info, or you need me to clarify anything, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Put at the bottom on your CSS file:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #titlesec {
    /*Put your argument with 100% Eg. width: 100%*/
  }
  #forms {
    /*Put your argument with 100% Eg. width: 100%*/
  }
}
```

and for skewed text try with this:

```
#titlesec, #forms {  
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* Webkit */    
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */     
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */    
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */     
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */ 
}
```

It would be like that:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
      #titlesec, #forms {  
         white-space: pre-wrap;      /* Webkit */    
         white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */     
         white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */    
         white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */     
         word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */ 
      }

      #titlesec {
        /*Put your argument with 100% Eg. width: 100%*/
      }
      #forms {
        /*Put your argument with 100% Eg. width: 100%*/
      }
    }
```

I hope it's helps ;)

Comment: unfortunantly it didn't. This thing is so hard. It could be the margins.

Comment: I have been testing your code and I am not able to see the error, I have tried if there were the margins, if the width, etc. Theoretically the text itself should adapt to the width of the div, unless there is an element that is not capable and that is why it causes the error, that is my conclusion, I am sorry for not being able to do more, I hope that this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out. 
I took away the position: relative, and left:25% from both the #testsec and #forms ID and instead typed in margin: auto. Worked like a charm. Hopes this helps other people struggling with positioning elements in CSS.